# select tag with hashes.map function

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about the getHashes(), there is a map-function that I want to list the hashes in a  tag. The listItems is not defined... why? 
Can I get some help with this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios                from 'axios';

class Filter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            hash: [
                "aSj1T", "CD6oL"
            ]
        }
    } 
    getHashes(){
        const hashes = this.state.hash;
        const listItems = hashes.map((hashes) => <option>{hashes}</option>);

        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){       
            const hashUrl = "https://api/v1/hashes/" + hashes[i];

        axios.get(hashUrl)
            .then((response) => {
                const data = response.data[0];

                this.state.hash.push(data.hash);
            })

            .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            }); 
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <select name="select" 
              type="select" value={this.getHashes}>
              {listItems}
              </select>
            </div>
           );
          }
export default Filter;
```

I stripped down the code, it is with reux axios and much more on my text editor. But i hope you can run this in your text editor to help. It is not tested. If you just explain it is also cool.

Comment: why select's value is getHashes? getHashes is an async function, not a select value

Answer (score 1):

1- `this.state.hash.push(data.hash);` is not a good idea you are mutating the state not changing it by `setState`

2- `listItems` is defined inside the function `getHashes` but never been added to the state or the component instance so you don't have access to it inside the render function

It is not obvious what you are trying to achieve by setting the value of `select` to a function

Comment: Thanks, I think the issue was that it was not defined because it wa not in the render function as you said. Thumbs up!